# how to add Double and Char arrays with each other in my scientific calculator program

Tags: java, android, arrays

i have two arrays.

```
double number[] = new double[5];
char oper[] = new char[4];
```

in my program when user press any operator sign like +,-,*,/ the number array is taking user input for example if he is entering 345 it is taking and saving it in number[0] and [0] become [1] and also save the current operation input from user and save it in oper[0] and so on.
but i dont know how can i get the result using both arrays.
i am pasting whole code here.

```
package com.example.calculatortesting;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView textdisplay;
    EditText currentcalc;
    EditText et1;
    double number[] = new double[5]; //for saving numbers in array
    char oper[] = new char[4];   //for saving operation in array
    int numposition = 0;           //for position of number array
    int operposition = 0;           //for position of operation array
    double currentnum;          //saving current number before operation
    int last_button = 0;        //checking last button pressed
    char operator;              //saving pressed operation value
    String newnum = "";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculator);
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        textdisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        currentcalc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
        Button b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
        Button b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b4);
        Button b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b5);
        Button b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b6);
        Button b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b7);
        Button b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b8);
        Button b9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b9);
        Button b0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b0);
        Button multiply1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiply);
        Button divide1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divide);
        Button plus1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
        Button minus1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
        Button equal1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.equal);
        Button clear1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        Button back1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backspace);
        Button dot1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decimal);
        Button plusminus1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plusminus);
        Button percent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.percent);
        Button shift = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shift);

        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        b4.setOnClickListener(this);
        b5.setOnClickListener(this);
        b6.setOnClickListener(this);
        b7.setOnClickListener(this);
        b8.setOnClickListener(this);
        b9.setOnClickListener(this);
        b0.setOnClickListener(this);
        multiply1.setOnClickListener(this);
        divide1.setOnClickListener(this);
        plus1.setOnClickListener(this);
        minus1.setOnClickListener(this);
        equal1.setOnClickListener(this);
        clear1.setOnClickListener(this);
        back1.setOnClickListener(this);
        dot1.setOnClickListener(this);
        plusminus1.setOnClickListener(this);
        percent.setOnClickListener(this);
        shift.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void currentcalcmethod(String currentcalcoper) {
        currentcalc.setText(currentcalc.getText() + currentcalcoper);
        currentcalc.setSelection(currentcalc.getText().length());
    }

    void number() {

    }

    void oper() {
        number[numposition] = currentnum;
        oper[operposition] = operator;
        numposition ++;
        operposition++;
        currentnum= 0;
}
void result (){

    double total;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (double num : number) {
        for (char op : oper){
        builder.append(num + op);
        total = num+op;
        et1.setText(Double.toString(total));
    }}

}

public void shownum(String number) {

    newnum = newnum + number ;
    currentnum = Double.parseDouble(newnum);
    et1.setText(Double.toString(currentnum));
}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if (v.getId() == R.id.b0) {
            currentcalcmethod("0");
            shownum("0");
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.b1) {
            currentcalcmethod("1");
            shownum("1");

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.b2) {
            currentcalcmethod("2");
            shownum("2");
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.b3) {
            currentcalcmethod("3");
            shownum("3");
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.b4) {
            currentcalcmethod("4");
            shownum("4");
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.b5) {
            currentcalcmethod("5");
            shownum("5");
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.b6) {
            currentcalcmethod("6");
            shownum("6");
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.b7) {
            currentcalcmethod("7");
            shownum("7");
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.b8) {
            currentcalcmethod("8");
            shownum("8");
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.b9) {
            currentcalcmethod("9");
            shownum("9");
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.plus) {
            currentcalcmethod("+");
            operator = '+';
            oper();
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.minus) {
            currentcalcmethod("-");
            operator = '-';
            oper();
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.percent) {
            currentcalcmethod("%");
            operator = '%';
            oper();
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.divide) {
            currentcalcmethod("/");
            operator = '/';
            oper();
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.multiply) {
            currentcalcmethod("*");
            operator = '*';
            oper();
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.decimal) {
            currentcalcmethod(".");
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.equal) {
            result ();
            currentcalcmethod("=");

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.backspace) {
            if (currentcalc.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                int start =0;
                int end2 = currentcalc.getText().toString().length() - 1;
                String newText2 = currentcalc.getText().toString()
                        .substring(start, end2);
                currentcalc.setText(newText2);
            }
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.clear) {
            textdisplay.setText("");
            currentcalc.setText("");
            number = null;
            oper = null;
            numposition = 0;
            operposition = 0;
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.plusminus) {

        }

        last_button = v.getId();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the user input as a String and parse it. Something like:

```
String userInput = "3+5";
List<Character> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
List<Character> operators = new ArrayList<>();
for (char c : userInput.toCharArray()) {
  if(Character.isDigit(c)){
    numbers.add(c);
  }
  else{
    operators.add(c);
  }
}
// Now loop through lists and perform the desired arthimetic operation based on operator
```

Comment: i dont have good understanding with arraylists. can you please make it easy to understand?

Answer (score -1):

You could put all of the inputs into a String and convert the string to a double to get an actual equation.

```
String ans = Double.toString(number[0]) + 
             Char.toString(oper[0]) + Double.toString(number[1]); //could use a loop to enter all values != null

ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript"); // build-in javascript engine allows for string equations.
    try {
        System.out.println(engine.eval(ans));
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Something like that.

Comment: i am developing a scientific calculator which is taking input from user. when user input the number and oper [1] values are always changing. so i am adding all the values entered by the user even those are 4 or 5 or so on.

Comment: You'd get a NumberFormatException.

Comment: Solved the NumberFormatException problem, my apologies.